# Why my text and button don't show up and are covered by my image?

Tags: android, kotlin

Why my text and button don't show up? Text & button shows up when I delete ImageView. I have tried both LinearLayout & RelativeLayout. None of them works.
Here are my codes.
LinearLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/before_cookie"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/before_eating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="18dp"
        android:textSize="36dp"
        android:text="I'm so hungry!"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="36dp"
        android:text="Eat Cokkie"
        android:onClick="eating" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Result for LinearLayout
[image]

RelativeLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/before_cookie"
        android:src="@drawable/before_cookie"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/before_eating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/before_cookie"
        android:layout_margin="18dp"
        android:textSize="36dp"
        android:text="I'm so hungry!"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/before_eating"
        android:textSize="36dp"
        android:text="Eat Cokkie"
        android:onClick="eating" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Result for RelativeLayout
[image]

Left Emulator is different than right preview.
[image]

Comment: Because your image is too big which hides the other widgets. Put it in _NestedScrollView_ or just give fixed height and width to imageview.

Comment: How to put the image in _NestedScrollView_?

Comment: Just put your all your UI widgets in _NestedScrollView_

Comment: Still don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your image is bigger than `ImageView`, so by default it gets shrinked to fit inside. problem is that when `ImageView` shrinks image and draw it then it won't rescale/shrink its bounds... so `ImageView` still "thinks" it is bigger/higher than needed and pushes out other/later `View`s. consider adding [android:adjustViewBounds="true"](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/android-imageview-adjustviewbounds-demystified-2f91ce7fe349) for `ImageView` for fixing this, personally I think `adjustViewBounds` and desired `scaleType` params should be set always for all `ImageViews` just for ommiting problems such yours

latter improvement would be to place whole linear inside `ScrollView`, just like other answer suggests (but this isn't standalone fix)

Comment: There are few things you wrote that I don't understand. (1) Does "own content" that you wrote = the emulator screen in my case? (2) Becase` ImageView` still "thinks" it is bigger/higher than needed so my `ImageView` covers over my text and button? (3)Even the `ImageView` "thinks" it is bigger/higher than needed, my text and button should be on top of my image. Before adding your codes, I tried to move `ImageView` to be the 1st section and the last section since I thought maybe my text and button were covered by my image but that didn't work.

Comment: (1) "own content" - `ImageView` setting image for itself. (2) your `ImageView` was taking whole space (even with `layout_height="wrap_content"`), so nothing left for other `View`s, as (3) you have `layout_below` lines, they are making each view is drawn under another (vertical axis). if you want to draw `Button` and `TextView` ON (top of) `ImageView` (covering it a bit) then just remove `layout_below` lines

Comment: I go with RelativeLayout now. Pls see the last pic above. Now the Left Emulator is different than right preview. I can barely see the button in emulator. How do I fix this?

Comment: Regarding the emulator and Android Studio showing the different view, Added the reason in my answer please refer it

Comment: note that your app will look differently (at least a bit) on different screen size and density devices. btw., you can accept only one answer and you switched check mark to person which just copied my solution with `adjustViewBounds`. always worth helping new users... still good luck

Comment: Sorry. I didn't know I can only accept one answer. I check your answer again.

Comment: Buddy, I didn't copied your answer but updated my answer with your solution because without scrollview your solution might not have worked at 1st place, and you can see before my edit to my answer of adding` adjustViewBounds` I mentioned that she might already got it fixed by following your solution.
So please don't blame. 
She is new and she might have thought she can mark answer again and again, so please don't blame it on me please

Comment: I appreciate both of your time in answering my question. Since you have spent time, you must think my question have some value. Would you please up vote this question? This question will benefit others in the future as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Regarding the emulator and Android Studio showing the different view, the reason is your emulator screen size is of 4.7"inch screen while the pixel 3 you are using to preview in Android studio have 5.5"inch screen.

:::::::::::::::

The reason this is happening to you, is you choose `wrap_content` as height width means for big images your image view will take more area to wrap the content without changing at aspect ratio.

Your same code for a smaller image will show you the button and texview you are missing.

so if you want your image as `wrap_content` you should add your layout in scrollview else you can specify some fixed height and width to your `ImageView`.

```
  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/before_cookie"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/before_eating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="18dp"
        android:textSize="36dp"
        android:text="I'm so hungry!"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="36dp"
        android:text="Eat Cokkie"
        android:onClick="eating" />
</LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: I use emulator api 22. After I copy and paste your codes and run the them, the result is I get this long screen that I can scroll down but the text and button are still missing.

Comment: I think you already got the idea from accepted answer, `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

Comment: Regarding the emulator and Android Studio showing the different view, Added the reason in Answer please refer it

Comment: I accept your answer too. How do I modify the preview size to match my emulator size?

Comment: from android studio preview screen click on `Devices` you will be able to see all the other sizes available to you, see if you have any 4.7" inches there.

Comment: @Lisa Baron - you can accept only one answer. and you've unchecked my proper solution and switched to answer, which was modified until successful result, probably thanks to pointed `adjustViewBounds` attr in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 ways:

1. Add ScrollView
2. Fixed width & height of ImageView

Answer (score 0):

Copy this code and paste in your layout file. Please let me know if this works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/before_cookie"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/before_cookie"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/before_eating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/before_cookie"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:text="I'm so hungry!"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="36dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/before_cookie" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:onClick="eating"
        android:text="Eat Cokkie"
        android:textSize="36dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/before_eating" />

     </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

What I Did :

1. I used ScrollView as the parent layout.
2. Now I used ConstraintLayout in which I put the widgets. (ImageView, TextView and Button)
3. After that, I set the constraints to arrange them properly and also used margins.

Now it should not cause any problems.

I used ConstraintLayout so the widgets get arranged properly.

I hoped its working now. Thank you...

Comment: The text and button shows up but the screen becomes very long with a lot of space above and below the image which is not what I am looking for. Don't know if it looks the same way in your computer as I describe. Pls give this question a up vote if you think this question is meaningfor.

Comment: Please try deleting the lines where i added marginTop="20dp". I thought it would be comfortable for you

Comment: Even I deleting the lines of "20dp". A lot of space above and below the image still exist. Both spaces above and below the image are like 200dp.

Comment: can you please send your drawable image file so i can test in my emulator?

Comment: 1 pic: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gae-supplemental-media/before-cookiejpg/before_cookie.jpg              2 pic:  https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gae-supplemental-media/after-cookiejpg/after_cookie.jpg

Comment: Set ImageView height to 440dp.its working in my case